# How do I write a jquery function that accepts a callback as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I Have the following function.

```
function ChangeDasPanel(controllerPath, postParams) {

    $.post(controllerPath, postParams, function(returnValue) {

        $('#DasSpace').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000, function() {

            $('#DasSpace').contents().remove();

            $('#DasSpace').append(returnValue).css("display", "block");

            $('#DasSpace').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);

        });

    });

};
```

But I want to be able to call it like this

```
ChangeDasPanel("../Home/Test", {} ,function (){
  //do some stuff on callback
}
```

How can I implement support for callbacks in my function?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
function ChangeDasPanel(controllerPath, postParams, f) {
  $.get(
    controllerPath, 
    postParams, 
    function(returnValue) {
      var $DasSpace = $('#DasSpace');
      $DasSpace.hide(
        "slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000, 
        function() {
          $DasSpace.contents().remove();
          $DasSpace.append(returnValue).css("display", "block");
          $DasSpace.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        }
      );
      if (typeof f == "function") f(); else alert('meh');
    }
  );
};
```

You can pass functions like any other object in JavaScript. Passing in a callback function is straight-forward, you even do it yourself in the `$.post()` call.

You can decide whether you want to have your callback called as part of the `$.post()` callback or on its own.

Comment: exactly what I've been trying to do for the past 30 minutes. Thanks! helped me out

Comment: Thanks for the “if (typeof f == "function") f();” part. I have been looking for that!

Answer (score 23):

You know that global variables and functions are evil, so why not put your's into the jQuery namespace:

```
$.extend({
  myFunc : function(someArg, callbackFnk){
    var url = "http://example.com?q=" + someArg;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){

      // now we are calling our own callback function
      if(typeof callbackFnk == 'function'){
        callbackFnk.call(this, data);
      }

    });
  }
});

$.myFunc(args, function(){
  // now my function is not hardcoded
  // in the plugin itself
});
```

Read this post to get a better understanding: [Creating callback functions in jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html)

Comment: Cool. How can i create anonymous function like in Jquery itself `$.hide(555, function()){})` ??
Or callbackFnk is the answer?

Comment: Yeap, `callbackFnk` is just a local variable. As you can see in the example, we are passing an anonymous function: `$.myFunc(args, function(){})`.

Comment: Thanks once again! One more question, will it fire after the main func finish?

Comment: Nope, it will fire within the main function (within the `myFunc` call).

Answer (score 15):

If I understand you correctly, it's as easy as setting another parameter and calling the variable as a function:

```
function foo(mycallback) {
    mycallback();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you use an object that you can pass through to the function. It is much more jQuery like and it saves you having x named parameters which is hard to maintain as it can get unwieldy when you get past 3 params.

e.g

```
function callingFunction(){

      var fnSettings: {
        url: someUrl,
        data: params,
        callback : function(){}
      };


      yourFunction( fnSettings );

}

function yourFunction( settings ) {

      $.post( settings.url, settings.data, settings.callback );

}
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest answer (I wrote something similar, so I might be biased)